# How to fix Ant javascript tags for M1 Mac?

Tags: javascript, java, ant, apple-m1

Ant javascript tags don’t work on Big Sur
Our ant script doesn’t work on our new M1 build machine doesn’t work because it has a javascript tag, and it javascript (Nashorn) was removed from Java in Java 15.

> build.xml:5: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript

> Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself. GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option.

I have searched all over for a Nashorn or Graal that works with Java15 but can’t find anything. The https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases skips from Java11 to 16.

Any idea how get our javascript tags working again?

Comment: Install an older JDK? You got a brand new M1 build machine, and you upgraded your JDK at the same time without giving it any thought?

Comment: I didn't update my JDK, it's a new machine. I would prefer to install a compatible javascript engine and downgrade the JDK. I don't know what would happen if I downgraded my JDK.

Comment: You don't need to install a Javascript engine if you downgrade to JDK <15. You indirectly updated the JDK by getting a new machine, now you need to either downgrade to the JDK you were using before, or decide on another JDK version to use if you decide the old one isn't good enough. The current one won't work as you've already learned, so you'll have to do *something*.

Comment: I would rather install javascript engine like Nashorn or Graal. Otherwise aren't I blocked from future JDK versions?

Comment: You can install an earlier JDK to get Nashorn back, or you can install the experimental Graal 16 for a later JDK (I'm assuming you have OpenJDK 15 now). You could also get rid of the javascript tags in your ant file somehow, so you don't even need the engine. You can also keep on building with JDK <15 until it becomes an issue again, maybe your software doesn't last long enough for it to become an issue?